# Intranet Updates through the Announcements WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, intranet, announcements

I'm setting up our intranet with SharePoint and the management wants me to set up a feed similar to Twitter on our homepage.

**setup an announcement webpart** on every team subsites (we have 8 teams), then set up our Intranet homepage so that the announcement webpart of the intranet gets a constant feed from those. I could set up a workflow so that everyone receives a weekly email of the new announcement feed just like twitter does.

1) Would this solution work without me needing to manually update things?

2) How would I go about automating the type of pictures associated with every announcement? We have 8 teams that have their own respective logo, and it'd be great to incorporate them in the feed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution would work, not going to need any manual updates.

As for team's logos, you could go to the list settings and add new Image Column which will store logo. Than with a workflow on item created you could set logo url to this field. It would be the great idea to store url somewhere on the team site, to not modify workflow on every change.